# Matching the name and size of a file

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm having some trouble integrating two pieces of code.  The first checks the size of a file and the next one loops trough a SQL database and looks for a matching name for a file. I basically want to check if it's a new file or if the file has changed since I logged some of it's data last time.

This gets the size of each file in the directory

```
 // Make a reference to a directory.
        DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo("C:\\Users");
        // Get a reference to each file in that directory.
        FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();
        // Display the names and sizes of the files.
        MessageBox.Show("The directory {0} contains the following files:", di.Name);
        foreach (FileInfo f in fiArr)
            MessageBox.Show("The size of" + f.Name + " is " + f.Length + " bytes.");
```

This code loops untill it finds a mach or untill all entries has been looked trough.

```
  try
            {
                // LINQ query for all files containing the word '.txt'.
                var files = from file in
                                Directory.EnumerateFiles("C:\\Users")
                            where file.ToLower().Contains(".txt")
                            select file;

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                //Get path to HH file
                filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file);

                tempString = "";

                //Keep looking trough database utill database empty or HH found
                while (inc != numberOfSessions && (filename != tempString))
                { 

                    sessionRow = sessions.Tables["Sessions"].Rows[inc];
                    tempString = sessionRow.ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString();

                    inc++;
                }
```

Lets say ItemAttay.GetValue(2) returns the saved size of a file. How can i most efficiently keep the while loop going if

inc != numberOfSessions && (filename != tempString) && (sessionRow.ItemArray.GetValue(2) == f.length)

Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Do you care if a file's contents change but the size stays the same?  If so, the "check if file size has changed" criterion won't work.  Maybe compute a hash instead?

Comment: I only wan't to know if it's a new file or if something has been appended to it. It will never (should never i guess) get any smaller. How would you go about computing a hash?

Comment: The base class of the built-in .NET hash functions is [HashAlgorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.aspx).  There is some really old documentation that describes computing file hashes at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307020.

Comment: Can you use this code to create hash tags created from files? It seems to me like it only compares strings. I tried the code and used the path to 2 identical files in different directories and it said that they were different. Am I supposed to load the entire content of a file into sSourceData and then create the hash tag? Thanks for helping me out by the way!

Comment: To hash the contents of files, I'd recommend [HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Stream)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xa627k19.aspx).  If you pass this method a `FileStream` - perhaps one created by [File.OpenRead](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.openread) - you can hash the *contents* of the file, rather than the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.Data;



    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var files1 = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(args[0],
                "*.txt",
                SearchOption.AllDirectories));


            List<FileData> ListFiles = new List<FileData>();

            for (int i = 0; i < files1.Count; i++)
            { 


            FileInfo file = new FileInfo(files1[i]);
            FileData _tmpfile = new FileData(file.Name.ToString(), file.Length, 
                File.GetLastWriteTime(files1[1]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"),
                File.GetLastAccessTime(files1[1]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd H:mm:ss"));
            ListFiles.Add(_tmpfile);
            }

            DataSet sessions = new DataSet();
            DataTable dt = sessions.Tables["Sessions"];
            for (int i = 0; i < ListFiles.Count; i++)
            {
                //compares every file in folder to database
                FileData _tmp = ListFiles[i];
                for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (_tmp.GSFileName == dt.Rows[i][0].ToString())
                    { 
                        //put some code here
                        break; 
                    }

                    if (_tmp.GSSize == long.Parse(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString()))
                    {
                        //put some code here
                        break;
                    }

                }


            }



        }
    }
    public class FileData
    {
        string FileName = "";

        public string GSFileName
        {
            get { return FileName; }
            set { FileName = value; }
        }
        long Size = 0;

        public long GSSize
        {
            get { return Size; }
            set { Size = value; }
        }
        string DateOfModification = "";

        public string GSDateOfModification
        {
            get { return DateOfModification; }
            set { DateOfModification = value; }
        }
        string DateOfLastAccess = "";

        public string GSDateOfLastAccess
        {
            get { return DateOfLastAccess; }
            set { DateOfLastAccess = value; }
        }

        public FileData(string fn, long si, string dateofmod, string dateofacc)
        {
            FileName = fn;
            Size = si;
            DateOfModification = dateofmod;
            DateOfLastAccess = dateofacc;

        }

    }
```